# Creating a nested matrix from two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix and two lists:

```
matrix = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
a = {{1, 2, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 3}, {8, 5, 5, 8}}; 
d = {{I, 2, -I}, {I, 1, -1}, {4, I, 0}};
```

I am trying to do write a code as psudo-code here to joined a and b and add them to matrix:

```
Do[matrix[[i, j]] = AppendTo[a[[i]], a[[j]]], {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}];
```

the desired result is as below

```
matrix = 
  {{{1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, d[[1, 1]]}, 
    {1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, d[[1, 2]]}, 
    {1, 2, 2, 1, 8, 5, 5, 8, d[[1, 3]]}}, 
   {{3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, d[[2, 1]]}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, d[[2, 2]]}, 
    {3, 4, 4, 3, 8, 5, 5, 8, d[[2, 3]]}}, 
   {{8, 5, 5, 8, 1, 2, 2, 1, d[[3, 1]]}, 
    {1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, d[[3, 2]]}, 
    {8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8, d[[3, 3]]}}};
```

I would be so glad to have a way to obtain the result. Also, it will be good if I have a final matrix in horizontal shape for its sub_matrices in the nested final matrix instead of column shape for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xavier's comment with an additional `Partition` gives:

```
Partition[Flatten /@ Transpose[{Tuples[a, {2}], Flatten@d}], Length@d]
```

[image]

I think this is what the OP had in mind but it doesn't correspond to the next to last row of his "desired result."

Comment: using of `Tuples` is very interesting and intelligent.

Answer (score 6):

```
MapThread[
 Append,
 {Outer[Join, a, a, 1], d},
 2
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's build your matrix in three steps.

```
a = {{1, 2, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 4, 3}, {8, 5, 5, 8}};
d = {{I, 2, -I}, {I, 1, -1}, {4, I, 0}};

m1 = Join[#, #] & /@ a
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}, 
>  {3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3}, 
>  {8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8}}
> ```

```
m2 = ConstantArray[#, 3] & /@ m1
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}, 
>   {1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}, 
>   {1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}}, 
>  {{3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3}, 
>   {3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3}, 
>   {3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3}}, 
>  {{8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8}, 
>   {8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8}, 
>   {8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8}}}
> ```

```
matrix = MapThread[Append, {m2, d}, 2]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, I}, 
>   {1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2}, 
>   {1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, -I}}, 
>  {{3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, I}, 
>   {3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1}, 
>   {3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, -1}}, 
>  {{8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8, 4}, 
>   {8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8, I}, 
>   {8, 5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 8, 0}}}
> ```

This, of course, can be nested into one expression.

```
matrix = MapThread[Append, {(ConstantArray[#, 3] & /@ (Join[#, #] & /@ a)), d}, 2]
```

But it is much harder to understand how it works in that form.

#### Update

Another approach to solving this problem is to break it into two parts -- to first write a helper function that can generate any single row of the desired matrix and then map that function over the two given matrices to produce the desired matrix.

```
helper[aRow_, dRow_] := 
  MapThread[Append, {ConstantArray[Join[aRow, aRow], 3], dRow}]

matrix = MapThread[helper, {a, d}]
```

#### Update 2

```
matrix // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

Comment: No this is not things which I have searching!!

Comment: @Ackaran. Why does neither of these methods work for you? They both produce the matrix you asked for.

Comment: So sorry but I just saw the line above "This of course can be", I could not see the continued writing. it is correct. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Your answer was so helpful because it was step by step approaching.

Comment: But I had thought this is correct but your answer after checking is not which I am searching. My figure is removed on my post I will posted again. output must be similar to that. I think eldo write the correct one.

Comment: @Ackaran. See update 2. It is only a matter of display formatting. I didn't think you needed to be instructed about that.